# base64 decode 2 items in array and still output for json?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

So I have this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, category, tag, title, titleImage, thumbImage, pubDate, shortCopy, fullCopy FROM articles WHERE ID=$IDparam");

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$output[]=$row;
}

echo(json_encode($output));
```

And I am looking to use base64_decode() on shortCopy and fullCopy and still get the same json output. I've tried adding this before the final echo...

```
$output['shortCopy']=base64_decode();
```

Edited:

I'd like to still output all of the SELECTed fields just want to run shortCopy and fullCopy via base64_decode().

Thanks in advance,

Mach

Answer (score 3):

Try changing:

```
$output['shortCopy']=base64_decode();
```

to:

```
$output['shortCopy'] = base64_decode($output['shortCopy']);
```

The problem was that nothing was being decoded, since you put the string to be decoded inside the "()" in base64_decode();

Comment: Before this change, my output would of been
    [{"ID":"01","category":"","tag":"","title":"","titleImage":"","thumbImage":"","pubDate":"","shortCopy":"c2hvcnQ=","fullCopy":"bG9uZw=="}]
and after decoding it changes to
    {"ID":"01","category":"","tag":"","title":"","titleImage":"","thumbImage":"","pubDate":"","shortCopy":"c2hvcnQ=","fullCopy":"bG9uZw=="},"shortCopy":"","fullCopy":""}
I'm trying to keep the first style of output just with the decode change.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: You didn't pass any parameter to the decode which you need to do.
Try this:

```
$output['shortCopy']=base64_decode($output['shortCopy']);
$output['fullCopy']=base64_decode($output['fullCopy']);
```

Answer (score 0):

So Daniel Lisik was correct, it's just I hadn't cleared up how my data was currently. So using his example just with a little change worked fine

```
$output[0]['shortCopy']=base64_decode($output[0]['shortCopy']);
$output[0]['fullCopy']=base64_decode($output[0]['fullCopy']);
```

Thanks guys.